# Versioning Web Parts in Kentico

Tags: web-parts, kentico

Is it possible to apply versioning to Web Parts on pages?

I found documentation on versioning for [Page properties here](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-and-using-page-versioning), and this is close to the functionality I am looking for -- just for Web Part data instead of Page data.

I did some tests dragging Web Parts onto a versioned page, and this does *not* create major nor minor versions of the page. I can save the page after making a Web Part change, to force a version update to be logged to the page, but rolling back this page version sadly does *not* affect the Web Part.

I also found [this documentation here](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/managing-sites/configuring-settings-for-sites/settings-versioning-synchronization/settings-object-versioning) about object versioning.  Seems to indicate that what I am looking for is *not* possible.  The only references to Web Parts were Web Part Layouts and Web Part Containers -- neither of which are places where content editors enter actual content.

Ideally, what I am looking for is some way to allow content editors to roll-back content changes that they've made on a page.  This includes the page properties itself (this seems to be included out-of-the-box), but also the Web Parts that have been added or updated on the page.  This is the part that does not seem possible. Have I missed some documentation somewhere?

I am running Kentico 11, if that matters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web parts are NOT specific to pages, they ARE specific to page templates.  Widgets are specific to pages but are based on web parts and web parts have no version history.  So you do have version history on page templates so if a web part configuration was changed, it would be with the history of the page template.

So short answer is you CANNOT apply versioning on web parts on pages, because it does not exist.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, Brenden, that makes sense!  

I also confirmed that you are correct! I was able to see versions applied on the page template itself after making a Web Part change, and also roll them back successfully.  

This is the answer I was looking for! Thank you!